# java application and x11 forwarding

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, ssh, x11-forwarding

I need to start jperf on virtual server. I configured X11 forwarding via ssh. xclock - is working. But if I start jperf I get:

```
    user@client-32:~/sandbox/jperf-2.0.2$ sh jperf.sh
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
            at sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getDefaultScreenDevice(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:77)
            at net.nlanr.jperf.JPerf.(Unknown Source)
```

java version:

```
    java version "1.7.0_03"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.1.1pre) (7~u3-2.1.1~pre1-1ubuntu3)
    OpenJDK Client VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

uname -a :

```
`Linux client-32 3.2.0-29-generic-pae #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:25:43 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

**Problem solved**
Need to add `-Djava.awt.headless=true` into jperf.sh should be like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

java -classpath jperf.jar:lib/forms-1.1.0.jar:lib/jcommon-1.0.10.jar:lib/jfreechart-1.0.6.jar:lib/swingx-0.9.6.jar net.nlanr.jperf.JPerf -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Comment: what is DISPLAY variable set to?

Comment: $ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:10.0  
and xclock is working I said it.

Comment: can you try setnev DISPLAY HOSTNAME:0.0 instead of localhost.

Comment: $ xclock 
Error: Can't open display: 192.168.77.120:0.0

Comment: I used to use host name for DISPLAY variable and it works for me. do not give ip of that host please try with host name the value return by `hostname` command.

Comment: No, not yet. I've installed oracle java 7 but I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run jperf in headless mode, for that you may need to edit jperf.sh, see:
http://javatechniques.com/blog/linux-x11-libraries-for-headless-mode/

if it's still not working, try with oracle jvm instead of openjdk one.